# Список в центре блока

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, никак не могу установить список в центре блока. Я уже пробовал устанавливать `text-align:center` как для блока так и для списка и даже `margin:0` auto для списка делал, но и это не помогает.

css:

```
#menu {
    width: 100 % ;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center
}
ul.top - menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*border:1px solid black*/
}
ul.top - menu li {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    float: left;
    /*border:1px solid black*/
}
```

html:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="top-menu">
        <li><a href="">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Общение</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Файлы</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Новости</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Биография</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Код в студию!

Comment: @Роман Соколов, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: попробуй, ответ ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Посмотрите, надеюсь поможет.](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/jmBJv/) Для родителя добавляем - text-align: center;, а для дочернего элемента - display: inline-block; и все работает.

Удачи.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
Для текста- text-align:center !important;
Для блока - margin:0 auto !important;
```

**!important** - используется когда перекрывается каким то другим стилем.
А так смотри конфликт в firebug-e. 
Посмотрел ваш код:

```
#menu{
    width: 100 % ;
    height: 40px;
    /*text-align: center - не нужно здесь */
}
/*убрал пробелы между top-menu */
#menu .top-menu{
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*border:1px solid black*/
}
/*либо*/
#menu ul{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    /*border:1px solid black*/
}
#menu li{
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    float: left;
    /*border:1px solid black*/
}
```

Вроде так. Не тестил.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете такое свойство как margin: 0 auto; то обязательно указывайте ширину блока иначе как он выровнит.

> ul.top - menu { margin: 0 auto;
> /*border:1px solid black*/ }

здесь нужно указать его ширину и все. width: 980px; тогда он выровнит по центру

Comment: разве он не берет ширину от родительского блока?

Comment: Это блочный элемент, а блочный элемент занимает 100% родителя, поэтому необходимо либо: задать ему фиксированную ширину и прописать margin: 0 auto;, либо сделать так, как предлагалось в ответе №2.

Удачи.